# Adding class to div only if user is logged in

Tags: php, css

I already asked this question, sry, but ill try again.

The question is: How do i bind css to a div, only if user is logged in?

I got following, and it is working(Also session startet and so on)

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
include("/view/leftmenu.php");  
}
```

Now i want to add 20% to margin-left on my maincontent. Maincontent comes after this.
So how do i activate some css to a div only when the user is logged in. PHP!!!!

Sry for asking again:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$class = "";
if (isSet($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $class = "addmargin";
}
?>
```

Then in your view/HTML/...

```
<div class="<?php print $class; ?>">...</div>
```

Now you just need something like this in your CSS

```
div.addmargin {
    margin: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Finally, a very perfect answer. And also no bullshit talk :D Accepted in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` do :

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
<style type = "text/css">
#maincontent{
    margin: 20%;
}
</style>

<!-- or add link to the style sheet -->

<link href="logged-in-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<?php endif; ?>
```